# Create row of images with no space between using Razor

Tags: razor

This seems to be similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282572/asp-net-mvc-razor-extra-space) but I've tried the suggestions there (except for the custom helper) and it hasn't helped.

I'm trying to create a row of images in Razor so that there is no space/gap between them. My Razor view code looks like this. Model is an int.

```
    string theNumber = String.Format( "{0:00000}", Model );

    foreach( char theChar in theNumber.ToCharArray() )
    { 
<img src="/images/odometer/@{@theChar}.gif" style="border-width: 0px;height: 20px;width: 15px;" alt="" />
    }
```

This is producing HTML that looks like the following.

```
        <img src="/images/odometer/0.gif" style="border-width: 0px;height: 20px;width: 15px;" alt="" />
<img src="/images/odometer/0.gif" style="border-width: 0px;height: 20px;width: 15px;" alt="" />
<img src="/images/odometer/1.gif" style="border-width: 0px;height: 20px;width: 15px;" alt="" />
<img src="/images/odometer/9.gif" style="border-width: 0px;height: 20px;width: 15px;" alt="" />
<img src="/images/odometer/7.gif" style="border-width: 0px;height: 20px;width: 15px;" alt="" />
```

Which results in the following displaying in the browser.

[image: Incorrect]

The line breaks in the HTML source are causing gaps between the images. What I really want is the HTML to be generated all on one long line, like this.

```
<img src="images/odometer/0.gif" style="border-width:0px;height:20px;width:15px;" /><img src="images/odometer/0.gif" style="border-width:0px;height:20px;width:15px;" /><img src="images/odometer/1.gif" style="border-width:0px;height:20px;width:15px;" /><img src="images/odometer/9.gif" style="border-width:0px;height:20px;width:15px;" /><img src="images/odometer/7.gif" style="border-width:0px;height:20px;width:15px;" />
```

Which would result in an image like.

[image: Correct]

I know one option would be to not use a loop. My number will always be five digits, so rather than looping over each character in the string I could simply write an img tag for each digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this works:

```
@{
    var htmlTemplate = "<img src=\"/images/odometer/{0}.gif\" style=\"border-width: 0px;height: 20px;width: 15px;\" alt=\"\" />";
    string theNumber = String.Format("{0:00000}", DateTime.Now);
}
@foreach (char theChar in theNumber.ToCharArray())
{ 
    @Html.Raw(string.Format(htmlTemplate, theChar))
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If there is a fixed number of digits and rendering is an issue, I'd either drop the `foreach` or try writing the whole statement on the same line.

Comment: That's certainly an option, and I have done that for now, but I can imagine a time when it won't be an option and I will be forced to use a loop so would like a better solution.