# VB - ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor extra whitespace rendered

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, whitespace

I am getting extra whitespace characters rendered in my horizontal list of anchor tags below.  This is causing a major CSS styling issue for me.

I know this question has been addressed as far as a C# workaround is concerned ([asp.net mvc razor extra space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282572/asp-net-mvc-razor-extra-space)), but can anyone help me with a VB workaround?  I don't have the advantage of curly braces to eliminate all whitespace in a single-line If condition.

I have managed to work around it for now by writing an HtmlHelper extension method, but this dynamic code is only used in one place (the master layout page).  It seems to me that this should really be done in the .vbhtml page.  Any arguments against this opinion are also welcome.

Here is the erroneous code, along with commented-out attempts at workarounds.  The goal is to create a horizontal list of "sibling" pages based on a site map, with slightly different styles for the current page's link and the link just before it.

```
@If Not (SiteMap.CurrentNode Is Nothing OrElse SiteMap.CurrentNode.ParentNode Is Nothing OrElse SiteMap.CurrentNode.ParentNode.ChildNodes.Count = 0) Then
    @<div id="contentPageMenu">
    @For Each childNode As SiteMapNode In SiteMap.CurrentNode.ParentNode.ChildNodes
        @* GENERATES AN EXTRA SPACE BETWEEN EVERY a TAG! *@
        If childNode Is SiteMap.CurrentNode Then
            @<a class="top_menu_button top_menu_button_selected" href="@childNode.Url">@Trim(childNode.Title)</a>
        ElseIf childNode.NextSibling Is SiteMap.CurrentNode Then
            @<a class="top_menu_button top_menu_button_before_selected" href="@childNode.Url">@Trim(childNode.Title)</a>
        Else
            @<a class="top_menu_button" href="@childNode.Url">@Trim(childNode.Title)</a>
        End If

        @*
        STILL GENERATES EXTRA WHITESPACE!
        If childNode Is SiteMap.CurrentNode Then @<a class="top_menu_button top_menu_button_selected" href="@childNode.Url">@Trim(childNode.Title)</a>ElseIf childNode.NextSibling Is SiteMap.CurrentNode Then @<a class="top_menu_button top_menu_button_pre_selected" href="@childNode.Url">@Trim(childNode.Title)</a>Else @<a class="top_menu_button" href="@childNode.Url">@Trim(childNode.Title)</a>End If
        *@

        @*
        CAN'T PARSE a OR If STATEMENTS!
        @<a class=@If childNode Is SiteMap.CurrentNode Then @<text>"top_menu_button top_menu_button_selected"</text> ElseIf childNode.NextSibling Is SiteMap.CurrentNode Then @<text>"top_menu_button top_menu_button_pre_selected"</text> Else @<text>"top_menu_button"</text> End If@<text> href="</text>@childNode.Url@<text>"></text>@Trim(childNode.Title)@</a>
        *@
    Next
    </div>
End If
```

P.S. - I know I still need to handle the "canonical URLs" issue for MVC, but that is outside the scope of this question.

Here is a visual example of the problem. The arrows are top-right positioned background images.

[image: Visual example of broken/working behavior]

Here is the CSS used to style these buttons:

```
a.top_menu_button
{
    background: url(../Images/top_menu_separator.gif) no-repeat right top #01376a;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    font-weight: bolder;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px 15px 2px 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

a.top_menu_button:hover
{
    font-family: inherit;
    font-style: italic;
}

a.top_menu_button_before_selected
{
    background: url(../Images/top_menu_separator_before_selected.gif) no-repeat right top #01376a;
}

a.top_menu_button_selected
{
    background: url(../Images/top_menu_separator_after_selected.gif) no-repeat right top #b9aa64;
    color: #01376a;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: I added the example images above.  The arrows are placed as right-positioned background images, while the rest of the anchor tag background is filled with the appropriate color.  This allows my list to be generated dynamically and accommodate any size string.  A whitespace rendered between each tag causes the gap seen above.  (The "working" image was generated by extending the HtmlHelper class, but I don't feel this is the proper way to accomplish a task only used in one page.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using @Code/@End Code blocks with the @: escape.  Also, it might be more readable if you make a variable for the thing that you're using If/Then/Else logic to determine.

```
@Code
If Not (SiteMap.CurrentNode Is Nothing OrElse SiteMap.CurrentNode.ParentNode Is Nothing OrElse SiteMap.CurrentNode.ParentNode.ChildNodes.Count = 0) Then
    @:<div id="contentPageMenu">
    For Each childNode As SiteMapNode In SiteMap.CurrentNode.ParentNode.ChildNodes
        Dim aClassValue As String = ""
        If childNode Is SiteMap.CurrentNode Then
            aClassValue = "top_menu_button top_menu_button_selected"
        ElseIf childNode.NextSibling Is SiteMap.CurrentNode Then
            aClassValue = "top_menu_button top_menu_button_before_selected"        
        Else
            aClassValue = "top_menu_button"
        End If
        @:<a class="@aClassValue" href="@childNode.Url">@childNode.Title.Trim()</a>
    Next
    @:</div>
End If
@End Code
```

By the way, this is HTML - whitespace shouldn't matter.  Are you sure that's really causing you a problem?

-- EDIT --

Now that I see your CSS, the problem is clear.  You're using `inline-block`, which means that whitespace is significant in rendering, which is what you're finding.  You can fix this a couple of ways, both via CSS and not in your Razor.

1. You can add `float: left;` to your `a.top_menu_button` class and that will fix the problem.  Or...
2. You can take your outer `<div id="contentPageMenu">` and give it a style `style="word-spacing: -1em"`.  Then, add `word-spacing: 0;` to your `a.top_menu_button` class and that will fix the problem as well.

Try Googling "display inline block whitespace" and you'll get multiple hits talking about the problem and styling workarounds.  [This one](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/) and [this one](http://cssquirrel.com/2009/03/23/using-inline-block-and-word-spacing-to-make-columns-easier/) both give a clear and concise description of the problem and some ways around it.

Comment: This much cleaner (thank you), but it still results in the same error.  I have edited the post above to include a visual display of the problem when I get one whitespace character between each anchor tag.  Please also review the hyperlink above, which is to another StackOverflow thread describing the root issue.

Comment: Hmm... seems more like you're dealing with a rendering bug.  IE I assume?  Does it look right in FF/Chrome?  Do you have an example of the CSS you're using?  I wonder, what's the outcome of setting the `<a>` tags to have a 0 margin?

Comment: This is either a bug or design issue, but it is with Razor rather than the browser's rendering (as noted/accepted in the hyperlink I included).  It fails with the same result in IE 7/8/9, FF 5, and Chrome 12.  I have the margins and padding explicitly set.  I have verified, using FireBug, that the whitespace is the problem.  If I do a live edit and delete the one character of whitespace (rendered to be only one, as the raw response has many spaces), the problem instantly vanishes.  I have also done tests with the raw mark-up result to verify that these space characters are the problem.

Comment: Please review this known issue to understand the bug that I am trying to work around: [stackOverflow: asp-net-mvc-razor-extra-space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282572/asp-net-mvc-razor-extra-space).

Comment: I see what you're saying that there's a whitespace character outputted that you didn't want.  My question concerns why the whitespace affects the browser rendering at all.

Comment: I've added the CSS classes above.  That, along with the one comment I've posted to my own question, should answer your question.

Comment: Your CSS was helpful in seeing the problem.

Comment: Thanks!  Adding the float: left fixed the problem!  I'm sorry for the delayed response, but I had not noticed that you'd edited your answer after the last comment (my bad).

Comment: It actually looks like this isn't going to work for me after all.  The float:left approach poses the problem that the parent container (with background color and border) will not grow when there are enough menu items to cause a second horizontal line.  I didn't notice at first because I was testing in IE7, which is the baseline I must support and also doesn't have this same problem.  The word-spacing approach is appealing, but I can't get any of the less-than-IE8 corrections to work in my MVC page (so IE7 breaks).  I'm likely going to just stick with extending HtmlHelper at this point.