# ASP.NET MVC Razor extra whitespace rendered

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In Asp.net MVC, Razor inserts extra space between text blocks. I want to render a list this way: "1, 2, 3" but get "1 , 2 , 3".

```
@for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
{
  <text>@i</text>
  if (i != 2)
  {
    <text>, </text>
  }
}
```

Is there any ways to remove extra whitespace ?

Comment: Why do you have a space after the comma in the second `<text>` tag?

Comment: possible duplicate of [asp.net mvc razor extra space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282572/asp-net-mvc-razor-extra-space)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I want to render a list this way: "1, 2, 3"

Quick and dirty:

```
@string.Join(", ", Enumerable.Range(1, 3))
```

Obviously a custom helper seems more appropriate to the job of formatting something in the view:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString FormatList(this HtmlHelper html, IEnumerable<int> list)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Join(", ", list));
    }
}
```

and then simply:

```
@Html.FormatList(Model.MyList)
```

Answer (score 8):

You are seeing the extra whitespace between the number and the comma because your razor template includes a line break (which displays as whitespace in the browser) between the number and the comma:

```
@for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
{
  <text>@i</text> >LINE BREAK HERE<
  if (i != 2)
  {
    <text>, </text>
  }
}
```

I like [Darin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652522/asp-net-mvc-razor-extra-whitespace-rendered/6652871#6652871), and I would suggest removing your loop and replacing it with a more declarative statement, but if you don't want to go that far, try at least removing the line break:

```
@for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
{
    <text>@i</text>if (i != 2){<text>, </text>}
}
```

Comment: Why does any characters after the `</text>` get output? Shouldn't the line break be considered C# code?

Comment: @NetMage I don't know the why... I was just sharing my observations. I don't use much Razor anymore, so for all I know this may not even be the current behavior (this answer was from almost 7 years ago).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing out bits of text in different places each time round the loop, you could accumulate all the text in a `StringBuilder`, then outside the loop do `@stringBuilderObject.ToString()`.

Comment: That violates the whole point of using page templates, since it requires embedding the HTML in string literals. If you're going to do that, why have a view at all? Just generate the whole page in the controller.

Comment: @David, I am fairly new to MVC, but I'm not sure I understand your point. He isn't creating any HTML, just plain text. The `<text>` element is specific to Razor, it's used to indicate plain text.

Comment: Understood, but it seems that this is a greatly simplified example. If it's not, using a `string` would be more efficient than a `StringBuilder` for such a small block. Also, it might be worth your time to look at the the class that the runtime generates from the view. It takes care of a lot of the buffering that `StringBuilder` gives you behind the scenes.

Comment: @David, ok, but in normal .Net, if you're building up a string a piece at a time via a loop, a `StringBuilder` is generally a good way to go. Are you saying that the way Razor views are compiled means that just appending to a string (using `+=`?) is sufficient?

Comment: Yeah, you're right in that building a string by normal concatenation can be very, very slow since a copy gets created (along with the associated garbage collection) with each string addition. However, that's not how the compiled views work. I wouldn't even use `string +=` in this case - just let Razor take care of it like he's doing. Keeping the HTML in the view, and out of the compiled code, is, in my opinion, required - I shouldn't have to make code changes when a designer wants to add or remove a comma.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the source that is generated. When you look at the actual source you get:

```
  1
    , 
  2
    , 
  3
```

As you can see there is a lot of white space in there which browsers collapse down to a single space (look at the [definition for normal](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)).

Using a `StringBuilder` or `string.Join` is the way to fix this if all you're doing is outputting these three numbers. But if you're trying to do something else and this is a simplified example then [see this blog post](http://petewilliams.info/blog/2010/04/display-html-olul-list-as-comma-separated-sentence/) for a way of doing it using `ol/ul` and `li`s.

Answer (score -3):

I might assume that it is not issue of Razor, but rather  element is rendered with some margings.

1. Open FireBug (or Chrome or whatever) and see that it is really markup issue.
2. In you css file try to add

> text { margin: 0 }

Comment: The code shown won't actually render any `<text>` elements to the browser; this is just used by Razor to recognise blocks of text to render. See Scott Gu's explanation - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx